# Call a php function passing argument on a link in the same page and display the content in div

Tags: php, html

I need to call a function by passing argument on a HTML link in the same page

My code:

```
<?php
#array loop 
   foreach($new_array as $value){
         #pass the array to the function
         $input = inputFiles($value);

         # call the function on the click of link
         echo '<a href="#" id="inputLink" target="_blank">Input Link</a>';

         # output of the function in the div
         echo '<div id="inputLinkOutput" ></div>';
        }

   function inputFiles($value){
     # get the value and do the rest work
    }
?>
```

Please help.

Comment: I have no idea what this question means. In fact it just looks like a **DO IT FOR ME** request. But I still have no idea what you actually want done. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you pass `$_GET` variable via url like that:

```
<!-- lcoalhost/myPage.php -->
<a href='myPage.php?var1=123&var2=abc+bcd'>Link here</a>
```

And in PHP:

```
$var1 = $_GET['var1']; // => (string) '123'
$var2 = $_GET['var2']; // => (string) 'abc bcd'
```

Comment: Do I need to pass the php function name with the arguments?

Comment: No, since you will be redirecting directly to script, and not to function, you have to detect, that there is params and process them

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something like Ajax to achieve this. Here how you do this.

1. Create a ajax function which calls a method in a php file. Along with the call pass a parameter with a value. Because this will help in the server side to execute which function.
2. Then inside the PHP file create set of functions which you think will execute. (PHP function has been listed below)
3. Introduce a switch statement to navigate to specific function.

   `$param = $_GET['val'];`

   `switch($param){
    case '1' : methodA(); break;
    case '2' : methodB(); break;
    //and so on
   }
   methodA(){
          //do some logic
   }
   methodB(){
         //do some logic
   }`

Hope this helps.
Cheers!